# Can The Facebook Crawler See Base64 Images

Tags: angularjs, facebook, prerender

I have an angular app which is rendered for bots with prerender.io. The page is properly cached with an `og:image` tag and the cached pages also do have images visible. When trying to share the page, I cannot select any images.

[example of website (escaped fragment)](http://photoshop-battle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=battle/hillarious-clinton-vs-donald-dump)

When viewing the source, I can clearly see the meta tags.

[page in the facebook open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fphotoshop-battle.com%2F%23%21%2Fbattle%2Fhillarious-clinton-vs-donald-dump)

In the debugger I can not see any of my `og-meta tags`.

But when I checkout what the [facebook crawler sees](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fphotoshop-battle.com%2F%23%21%2Fbattle%2Fhillarious-clinton-vs-donald-dump), I can see the `og:image tag`

Question:

- Can the facebook crawler detect and render base64images?
- Why are all my og meta tags not visible to fb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Facebook crawler cannot use data URIs for open graph tags.

Comment: Thanks, just in the tag or in general (in the whole page)